# Place elements on page without disrupting the existing one - FFextension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want to append or overlay some divs over existing html page. Is there a way to achieve this without disrupting the existing html ecosystem, with extension maybe? Simple example with

[image: picture]
<sub>(source: [mozilla.net](https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/user-media/previews/full/178/178518.png?modified=1512497193))</sub>
.

Similar that Evernote has:

[image]

As far as code is concerned, I can inject or append the div element on page but that is not the point, I have to mod some css as well when I do that. Is there a way with a help of extension for that div to be independent from that page? To be **overlaid** to be precise.

> background.js

```
function change(){
  var bod = document.body;
  var divi = document.createElement('div');
  bod.appendChild(divi);
};

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', change());
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to show what you've tried already.

Comment: Develope an addon for your browser

Comment: What do you mean by "disrupt the existing html ecosystem?" Are you talking about document flow (something you can avoid with fixed positioning) or something else?